# Reproducing an ADAL.JS-authenticated request in Postman

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, postman, adal, adal.js

I have a .NET Web API and a small vanilla-JS app using [ADAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/), and I've managed to make them talk nicely to each-other and authenticate correctly.

If I `console.log` the token returned from `adalAuthContext.acquireToken()` and manually enter it as `Authorization: Bearer {{token}}` in Postman, I can also get a valid, authenticated, response from my backend.

However, I can't figure out how to configure Postman's built-in OAuth2.0 authentication UI to get me tokens automatically. I have managed to get tokens in several ways, but none of them are accepted by the backend.

**How do I configure Postman to get a token the same way the [ADAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/) library does?**

---

For completeness, here's some code:

Backend configuration:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

    app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
        new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { ValidAudience = "<app-id>" },
            Tenant = "<tenant>",
            AuthenticationType = "WebAPI"
        });

    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    app.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

ADAL.js configuration:

```
const backendUrl = 'http://localhost:55476';
const backendAppId = '<app-id>';

const authContext = new AuthenticationContext({
  clientId: backendAppId,
  tenant: '<tenant>',
  endpoints: [{ [backendAppId]: backendAppId }],
  cacheLocation: 'localStorage'
});
```

Actually making a request:

```
authContext.acquireToken(backendAppId, (error, token) => {
   // error handling etc omitted
   fetch(backendUrl, { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } })
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(console.log)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

So since the Azure AD v1 endpoint is not fully standards-compliant, we have to do things in a slightly weird way.

In Postman:

1. Select *OAuth 2.0* under Authorization
2. Click *Get new access token*
3. Select *Implicit* for Grant Type
4. Enter your app's reply URL as the Callback URL
5. Enter an authorization URL similar to this: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com`
6. Enter your app's application id/client id as the Client Id
7. Leave the Scope and State empty
8. Click Request token

If you configured it correctly, you'll get a token and Postman will configure the authorization header for you.
Now about that authorization URL.
Make sure you specify either your AAD tenant id or a verified domain name instead of `yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com`.
Or you can use `common` if your app is multi-tenant.
The `resource` is the most important parameter (and non-standards-compliant).
It tells AAD what API you want an access token for.
In this case I requested a token for MS Graph API, which has a resource URI of `https://graph.microsoft.com`.
For your own APIs, you can use either their client id or App ID URI.

Here is a screenshot of my settings:

[image: Postman OAuth 2 settings]